# How to fix ImportError: No module named packages.urllib3?

Tags: python, urllib2, urllib3, twill

I'm running Python 2.7.6 on an Ubuntu machine. When I run `twill-sh` (Twill is a browser used for testing websites) in my Terminal, I'm getting the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dep.py", line 2, in <module>
    import twill.commands
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twill/__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from shell import TwillCommandLoop
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twill/shell.py", line 9, in <module>
    from twill import commands, parse, __version__
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twill/commands.py", line 75, in <module>
    browser = TwillBrowser()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twill/browser.py", line 31, in __init__
    from requests.packages.urllib3 import connectionpool as cpl
ImportError: No module named packages.urllib3
```

However, I can import urllib in Python console just fine. What could be the reason?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a difference between the standard `urllib` and `urllib2` and the third-party `urllib3`.

It looks like twill does not install the dependencies so you have to do it yourself. Twill depends on `requests` library which comes with and uses `urllib3` behind the scenes. You also need `lxml` and `cssselect` libraries.

You can install them on terminal as follows:

`pip install requests`

`pip install lxml`

and

`pip install cssselect`

Comment: If you are installing generally you may need to switch to root or prefix each of the above commands with `sudo ` and type in your password after the first.

Comment: Yes, I've already installed these packages. First I installed python-pip, then using pip, I installed the other packages. There's no change in the error message. I even re-installed Python, but no luck.

Comment: I followed these steps having the same error, I needed to use sudo pip install --upgrade each time to make it work.

Answer (score 24):

If you already have 'requests' installed from a default build, you may have to

`sudo pip install --upgrade requests`

Credit to @bkzland from comment on previous answer:

> I followed these steps having the same error, I needed to use sudo pip
>   install --upgrade each time to make it work. – bkzland Dec 17 '15 at
>   12:57

---now, how do I make this a dependency in my setup.py?

Comment: in setup add `requires=['requests']`

Comment: Wouldn't that find the old version of requests, dependencies are now met, and we get the failure the OP has observed?

Comment: install_requires=['requests>=2.9']

Answer (score 9):

**python3**

```
#note that requests.packages.urllib3 is just an alias for urllib3
from urllib3 import disable_warnings
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
```

Comment: While this might answer the question, you should edit your answer to include some explanation for why this solves the issue in the question. This makes it more valuable to those who come across the same issue later on

Answer (score 5):

If you are having a RHEL based flavour, then:

`yum install -y python-requests`

Debian/Ubuntu based flavour:

`apt-get install -y python-requests`

Arch Linux based flavour:

`pacman -S python-requests`

Answer (score 4):

Problem solved by:

```
pip install --upgrade urllib3==1.19.1
pip install --upgrade requests
```

Comment: Yeap, this fixes it!

Answer (score 0):

It should be pointed out, you can also get this error if you are making the rookie mistake I did, running a python 3 script with the "old" python command, i.e. run the script as

```
python3 <script>.py
```

not

```
python <script>.py
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is depending on something implicitly by way of a sub-dependency. This style is tantamount to referring to a class's dunder-methods since a dependency's own dependencies may change (e.g say if `requests` stops using/exposing `urllib3`).

You can avoid this issue by being explicit with your dependencies, and expressing them (i.e `urllib3`) as a dependency in your `requirements.txt`/`pyproject.toml` file.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible due to requests version that you use, have different version of urlib3 then the one you are using in environment.