# boto3 on ubuntu trusty (ImportError: No module named packages.urllib3.exceptions)

Tags: python, ubuntu, boto3

I'm having trouble using the vendor-supplied boto3 on Ubuntu Trusty.  Has anyone else run into this issue, and if so how did you resolve?

FWIW, boto3 works fine in a venv on the same machine, so I think this is a packaging issue.  I need to make boto3 available on 1000+ machines, so using the vendor-supplied package is desirable.

I tried installing lxml, cssselect, and requests manually as described in 
[How to fix ImportError: No module named packages.urllib3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440060/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-packages-urllib3) but that didn't solve the problem.

Thanks,
Jeffrey

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS \n \l

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ sudo aptitude install python-boto3
....

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> boto3.__version__
'1.2.2'
>>> boto3.resource('s3')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/__init__.py", line 87, in resource
    return _get_default_session().resource(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 292, in resource
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/session.py", line 200, in client
    aws_session_token=aws_session_token, config=config)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/session.py", line 796, in create_client
    client_config=config, api_version=api_version)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 59, in create_client
    cls = self._create_client_class(service_name, service_model)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/client.py", line 76, in _create_client_class
    base_classes=bases)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 226, in emit
    return self._emit(event_name, kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/hooks.py", line 209, in _emit
    response = handler(**kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/utils.py", line 59, in _handler
    module = import_module(module)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/utils.py", line 52, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 13, in <module>
    from boto3.s3.transfer import S3Transfer
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 138, in <module>
    from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import ReadTimeoutError
ImportError: No module named packages.urllib3.exceptions
```

On the same machine, installing boto3 in a venv seems to work fine.  (At least I'm able to create a ServiceResource() object.)

```
vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ virtualenv venv-boto3
New python executable in venv-boto3/bin/python
Installing setuptools, pip...done.

vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ source venv-boto3/bin/activate
(venv-boto3)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ pip install boto3
Downloading/unpacking boto3
  Downloading boto3-1.4.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl (127kB): 127kB downloaded
...

(venv-boto3)vagrant@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19) 
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import boto3
>>> boto3.__version__
'1.4.4'
>>> boto3.resource('s3')
s3.ServiceResource()
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix ImportError: No module named packages.urllib3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440060/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-packages-urllib3)

Comment: Please don't use 'sudo' make any python package install, setup virtual development environment.