# python telegram bot - bot run error

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-telegram-bot

When I try to run a bot, I get this error message in the terminal:

```
zass@zass-system-product-name:~/python-telegram-bot/examples$python 
echobot.py
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/python_telegram_bot-8.0-
py2.7.egg/telegram/utils/request.py:38: UserWarning: python-telegram-
bot wasn't properly installed. Please refer to README.rst on how to 
properly install.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "echobot.py", line 8, in <module>
import telegram 
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/telegram/__init__.py", line 94, in 
<module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/telegram/bot.py", line 34, in 
<module>
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/telegram/utils/request.py", line 
33, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ptb_urllib3.urllib3
```

I'm running Python 2.7 on ubuntu, git and telegram bot are installed. - How can I fix it?

Comment: Did you install `urllib3`?

Comment: yes i installed urllib3

Comment: Do you use virtualenv? If yes, probably you didn't activate it

Comment: oh no can you explain what i must do please ?

Comment: If you run `pip freeze` you should see `urllib3` in a list. If there will not be this lib - you haven't installed it, or os block your installation because you aren't `root` user. You should use `sudo pip install urlib3`. If you don't know what is virtualenv - you don't use it)

Comment: i have urllib3==1.22

Comment: Try this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27440556/4900574. Or upgrade your packages and pip

Comment: i test that not work.

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure you have `urllib3` installed. Sometimes `urllib3` installation breaks. If for some reason your install of urllib3 is failing to include the `util` submodule, you could simply download the archive from the pypi page and copy the util folder from there to your `urllib3` install location.

You may also issue the command below to get an up-to-date version:

`sudo pip install urllib3 --upgrade`

Then, see where your module is by starting a python interpreter and check where the `urllib3` module is being loaded from:

`python -c "import urllib3; print urllib3.__file__"`

If all the above didn't work for you, make sure you're importing it right! and make sure there is no conflict.

Answer (score 0):

If you clone the python-telegram-bot repo you need to run the following command before installing the code:

`git submodule update --init --recursive`

Then install the code with `python setup.py install`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have 2 version of python and default version is 3.x
Try to check version of python 
`python -V`
if default version is 3 then run your code with python version 2.

```
python2 echobot.py
```

it can be python2 or python2.7

Also it can be cause of versions of libs