# Problems importing modules. Python version issue?

Tags: python-3.x

I am having some problems with the following. I have inherited a .py file that I need to use but I am obviously using a different python version to the author.

```
from datetime import datetime

import json, requests, os, time, sys

from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning

requests.packages.urllib3.disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
```

I get these errors;

```
E1101:Module 'requests.packages' has no 'urllib3' member
E0401:Unable to import 'requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions'
```

Any help pointing me in the direction of what is wrong would be great.

I am using Python 3.6.4 if that helps.

Comment: which OS you are on? Linux, Windows, macOS?

Comment: I am using macOS

Answer (score 1):

I suffered same issue, and this is what finally worked out on my computer:

**requests.urllib3.disable_warnings()**

Put this command anywhere after **import requests.**

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed `requests`?

```
pip3 install --upgrade requests
```

see [How to fix ImportError: No module named packages.urllib3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27440060/how-to-fix-importerror-no-module-named-packages-urllib3)

---

There's also another mention of this error here:
https://github.com/thp/urlwatch/issues/159

> I managed to resolve this problem on Ubuntu 14.04 by uninstalling the system pip (python3-pip) then using easy-install3 to reinstall the latest pip. After that I was able to upgrade requests (which refused to upgrade otherwise). I also needed to manually remove urllib3 and chardet from /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages.
>
> In summary: this problem was caused by using the distribution-installed Python 3, which is running a patched (and outdated) pip that will refuse to upgrade any distro-installed Python packages.

It looks like there's older version of requests installed.
On macOS I'd recommend installing python via [homebrew](https://brew.sh/) to avoid messing with system installation of python.

```
    brew install python3
    python3 -V
    pip3 install requests
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this. I installed requests already but i'll try this solution.

Comment: Updated instructions for macOS

Answer (score 0):

I realise this is a bit old, but I had the same issue and found that in python3 you can use **urllib3**

So in your case, instead of: 
`from requests.packages.urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning`

Use:
`from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a straight forward approach

```py
from urllib3 import disable_warnings
from urllib3.exceptions import InsecureRequestWarning
    
VERIFY_HTTPS = False
    
if VERIFY_HTTPS is not True:
    disable_warnings(InsecureRequestWarning)
```